# Border collapse not fit in following structure

Tags: html, css

I used border-collapse since long. Now, I am trying use border-collpase, it's not working.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #83CAFF;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #CC99CC;
}

.content {
  background-color: #FFCCCC;
}

.content>h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.ads {
  background-color: #CC99CC;
}

header,
footer,
.menu,
.ads,
.content {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #83CAFF;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>HEADER</h1>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <h3>MENU</h3>
    <span>ITEM 1</span>
    <span>ITEM 2</span>
    <span>ITEM 3</span>
    <span>ITEM 4</span>
    <span>ITEM 5</span>
  </div>
  <section class="content">
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </section>
  <aside class="ads">
    <h2>AD</h2>
    <h2>AD</h2>
  </aside>
</div>
<footer>
  <h1>FOOTER</h1>
</footer>
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: I think border-collapse working with display table. And here you can use it with display flex.

Comment: @Jamshaid So, do you have any idea how can I solve that here?

Comment: simply make the border 1px instead

Comment: @TemaniAfif Nope it still not a solution. In middle there are 2px.

Comment: @katen You may need to use border individually. Please see updated code snippet below

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code snippet.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #83CAFF;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #CC99CC;
}

.content {
  background-color: #FFCCCC;
}

.content>h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.ads {
  background-color: #CC99CC;
}

header,
footer,
.menu,
.ads,
.content {
  /*border: 2px solid black;*/  
}
header, footer {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.menu {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
}
.ads {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}
.content {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #83CAFF;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>HEADER</h1>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <h3>MENU</h3>
    <span>ITEM 1</span>
    <span>ITEM 2</span>
    <span>ITEM 3</span>
    <span>ITEM 4</span>
    <span>ITEM 5</span>
  </div>
  <section class="content">
    <h2>CONTENT</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </section>
  <aside class="ads">
    <h2>AD</h2>
    <h2>AD</h2>
  </aside>
</div>
<footer>
  <h1>FOOTER</h1>
</footer>
```